# GKE Autoprovisioning not creating node pools for large instances within resource limits

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE Cluster with Auto-Provisioning enabled, the cluster limits for cpu are 250 and memory is 1000GB. However creating a pod that requests 46 vCPUs and 200GB of memory results in the error `no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.resources.exceeded` from the autoscaler.

At first I thought this could be a quota thing, but I was able to manually spin up a node pool using the `n2-highmem-64` machine type and the workload scheduled as expected.

The cluster has no other workload in it other than the GKE system workloads and is currently sitting at 2cpus and 4GB of memory which should leave it loads of room for scaling up to handle with workload.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by defining a node affinity for the workload to use the n2 family:

```
nodeAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: cloud.google.com/machine-family
          operator: In
          values:
            - n2
```

Not sure why this is required as the docs suggest N2 machines are considered in auto-provisioning